# How to add a delay in For loop in kotlin android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, progress-bar

I want to animate the progress bar so i am setting its progress using for loop but the loop is too much faster that i can't see the animation . I want the code to add a delay in the loop , i tried using thread delay but not working -
here is the code

```
      private fun showProgress() {

    
        for(i in 0..100){
            
            Thread{
            binding.customProgressBar.progress=i
            Thread.sleep(100)

        }

    }
  }
```

**Solution** : Was not calling start method , but if there any other approach then please let me know

```
 private fun showProgress() {

    Thread {
        for (i in 0..100) {

            binding.customProgressBar.progress = i
            Thread.sleep(100)
        }

    }.start()


}
```

now i want to terminate the thread when fragment is on pause state .
how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using `kotlin` it is better to use `coroutine`, you can achieve your goal with something like this:

```
private suspend fun someProgress(scope: CoroutineScope) {
    val job = scope.launch {
        for (i in 0..100) {
            binding.customProgress.progress = i
            delay(100)
        }
    }

    // use job.cancel() for cancelling the job or use job.join() for waiting for the job to finish
}
```

you can learn more about `coroutine` and how it works in [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html).

Comment: I want to call job.cancel() when fragment is in pause state or stopped

Comment: Hmm. Where is the implementation of the `someProgress` method? You can store this job in a file, make that class `LifecycleObserver, listen for the desired lifecycle event, and then cancel this `job` when that event gets triggered

Comment: its under on create , will calling job.cancel() under onDetach()  method will work ?

Comment: ok it worked in onPause()